# Page breaks and merged cell styling in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in Excel, which in Normal Workbook View mode looks like this:

[image]

However when I am trying to print the document and if it spans multiple pages vertically, I get this:

[image]

Notice how the border is gone on the last row? This only happens for vertically merged columns. Styling (including borders) is fine for the rest of the columns on all rows. Does anyone have a clue why this happens and how to prevent it?